# What’s the difference between ‘absolutely’, “relatively” and nothing?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

1. It is absolutely hot.
2. It is relatively hot.
3. It is hot.

What’s the difference between three sentences?

I guess sentence 3 can be used instead of sentence 1 and sentence 2.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions and answers are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anything closed can be edited to bring it within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [MetaPhil](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because better suited for [EnglishSE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though isn't a philosophical question, I'll answer.

- It is absolutely hot.

It is hot within the [universe of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse#Universe_of_discourse).

- It is relatively hot.

It is hot within a subset of the universe of discourse.

- It is hot.

It is hot with no reference to the universe of discourse.

What is the universe of discourse? It's just everything that the adjective ([predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(philosophy)) in philosophical jargon) applies to. 'Hot' has several meanings, so let's provide a [context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_(language_use)). If we are using 'hot' to describe the recorded temperature of days in Chicago... it would be absolutely hot on a day when the new high temperature is recorded because no day hotter is known. But, let's say on Christmas day, the 25th of December it get's to 70 degrees F, well that's relatively hot, because December is a cold month generally. We're comparing December 25ths on record instead of all days of the year. Lastly, 'it is hot' expresses a proposition which is [ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity) in regards to what domain of discourse.